# Facebook application hash authentication via a C# based server application

Tags: javascript, c#, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following set-up:

- a C#  based server application
- a Flash-based computer-game client web application, coded in the JavaScript API for Flash running in an iFrame on the Facebook website.

I need help to figure out how to authenticate an authentication hash.

I don't know what the client needs to send to the server.

**Example**

In vk.com, i check the following:

> md5(app_id+user_id+secret_key) = auth_key.

I can get parameters with the following code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus( fnction(response) { }
```

The parameters returned are:

- signed_request
- userID
- expiresIn
- accessToken

I send the parameters to the server for authetication, which in turn allows a person to join a game.

I know it's possible to check requests to PHP-API on my HTTPS-hosting using C#, but I don't know how.

I think I might be able to check as follows:

```
$appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $app_secret);
```

...but I'm not sure what $appsecret_proof is.

I have a hunch that it is a constant variable that I can use for comparison, although I don't know what I'm supposed to compare it to.

Can anyone help?